# Value of object in stack changes

Tags: c#, winforms, stack, propertygrid

I'm trying to create an undo function for changes made in a PropertyGrid. To accomplish this I push an object to a Stack before assigning the object to the PropertyGrid. To my surprise the object in the stack changes accordingly to the changes made in the PropertyGrid.

Why is this happening?

```
public class Employee
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int employeeKey { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Name")]
    [Description("The name of the employee.")]
    public string employeeName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Active")]
    [Description("Indicates whether the employee is currently employed.")]
    public bool employeeIsActive { get; set; }
}

public partial class frmProperties : Form
{
    public object propertyGridObject;
    private Stack<object> _stack;

    public frmProperties()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmProperties_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _stack = new Stack<object>();
        _stack.Push(propertyGridObject);

        propertyGrid.SelectedObject = propertyGridObject;
    }

    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_stack.Count > 0)
        {
            propertyGrid.SelectedObject = _stack.Pop();
        }
    }
}

public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnViewProperties_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee()
        {
            employeeKey = 123,
            employeeName = "John Smith",
            employeeIsActive = true
        };

        using (frmProperties frm = new frmProperties())
        {
            frm.propertyGridObject = employee;
            frm.ShowDialog(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your employee object is a reference type. You need to clone the object (make a copy) since mutating any properties will affect both places you are referencing the object, there is only one copy of it in memory

Comment: Read about [Reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235). You will also fins this post useful [Value vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Comment: Have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78612/2146626.

Comment: You can serialize/deserialize the object, if you just need to roll back some properties. It won't preserve States, though. Your class could implement [ICloneable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable) (though a State is hard to reproduce anyway)

Comment: ... but it doesn't look like your class needs to preserve a State.